# Installing packages to end-of-lifed Ubuntu editions?

Tags: release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

i currently have 8.10 on my machine which for some reasons i can not upgrade to latest version
and i want to install some packages to it.but as you all must have guessed that i cant use `apt-get install` for anything.and i am fed up of satisfying the dependencies manually.so is there any alternate way of doing it?
can i download the server edition of it and get the .deb package from there.MySQL is the package that i am looking for!