# Are there still 9.10 software sources available?

Tags: software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing packages to unsupported Ubuntu editions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82291/installing-packages-to-unsupported-ubuntu-editions)
>   [Unable to install software on my ubuntu 9.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/unable-to-install-software-on-my-ubuntu-9-10)

I am still using Ubuntu karmic. I know I should upgrade but that is not so easy in the moment as I am in a country with very low bandwidth.

I need to install one package. Can I still find old software sources somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

unsupported releases are available from: [**old-releases**.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/).

To find particular package, you can:

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ls-lR.gz
zcat ls-lR.gz | less
```

and once you find the correct path, just download the packages, for example:

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mc/mc_4.6.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Comment: He could simply substitute the server in his `sources.list`, then use his preferred package manager.

Comment: @enzotib: I agree. But he want to get only one package, so I provided solution without the 'apt-cache update' to save the traffic.