# Updating karmic

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, apt, 9.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing packages to end-of-lifed Ubuntu editions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82291/installing-packages-to-end-of-lifed-ubuntu-editions)

I have a server which fails to do any updates

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security Release.gpg
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com karmic Release.gpg
...
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Sources
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Packages
  404  Not Found
...
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried performing an upgrade, but that fails, presumable because it cant access anything above!

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It currently is at :-

```
$ uname -a
Linux Gateway 2.6.31-23-generic-pae #75-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:14:10 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.10
Release:        9.10
Codename:       karmic
```

My question is, **can I just replace the `/etc/apt/sources.list` with one from the current disto?**

Currently contains lines like :-

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
```

Replace to so it has valid release :-

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
```

I see that it successfully *Hits* the packages.

```
...
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Packages
...
```

But just concerned if this is a good idea or not?

Comment: you should go from 9.10 to 10.04... via `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @fossfreedom thats the sort of nice and simple answer I was looking for! thanks. (And it should really be an answer...)