# Attempting to install Postfix on an Amazon EC2 instance and getting 404 not found

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing packages to unsupported Ubuntu editions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82291/installing-packages-to-unsupported-ubuntu-editions)

Basically I am trying to install postfix and getting 404 errors. Hopefully this screenshot will explain more:

[image]

Comment: Karmic is EOL that's why you're getting those errors, follow the instructions in the link

Answer (score 0):

That mirror http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ is not accessable from here also. Try other public repository mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

Try the link http://launchpadlibrarian.net/69807863/postfix_2.6.5-3ubuntu0.1_i386.deb

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to update from the repo using:

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```

   It could be that the file on repo was updated and the version you have in your cache isn't exist.
2. Try another repository.