# Couldn't update Ubuntu 8.04, apt-get update fails

Tags: apt, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing packages to end-of-lifed Ubuntu editions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82291/installing-packages-to-end-of-lifed-ubuntu-editions)

I am using Ubuntu 8.04 and I want to update it ,but it failed

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get update
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 8.04.4 _Hardy Heron_ - Release i386 (20100121.1) hardy/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 8.04.4 _Hardy Heron_ - Release i386 (20100121.1) hardy/restricted Translation-en_US
37% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.25)] [Connecting to security.u^37% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.25)] [Connecting to security.u^37% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.25)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189^Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security Release.gpg                                       
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.92.166), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/main Translation-en_US                            
  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/restricted Translation-en_US                      
  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy Release.gpg       ^[[15~                            
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.13), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Reading package lists... Done                        
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/Release.gpg  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.13), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/Release.gpg  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.92.166), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
root@ubuntu:~#
```

and my source.list file is :

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 8.04.4 _Hardy Heron_ - Release i386 (20100121.1)]/ hardy main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy universe
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates universe
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security universe
```

I couldn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that Ubuntu 8.04 has reached its end of support date; updates will no longer be available for this version.  You should consider upgrading to the latest LTS release, Ubuntu 12.04.

You can check the [End of Life chart here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for exact dates that specific releases reach (or have reached) the end of their support cycle.

Also check this question for a help on getting updates of end-of-lifed Ubuntu versions:

- [Installing packages to end-of-lifed Ubuntu editions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82291/installing-packages-to-end-of-lifed-ubuntu-editions)